# Algorithm for a Recursive function for a ArrayList and when a arrayList is empty return the exact array

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void count(ArrayList<Double> list) {

            if(list.empty()){    
                //how to do this **if list is null, return without doing anything **
            }

     //recursion function  

    if(total(list)>100){

    /*
     if total of list is more than 100, remove the first item and make a recursive call to count.

         For example, if list = [40, 30, 80]=150, list should become [20, 80]=100 

In the recursive function ,if the total of the array is greater than 100 ,using the function we have to remove one of any item and give a value that makes 100 with the rest of the numbers in the array.
if list = [40, 30, 80]=total is 150 ,so it is greater than 100
 then list should become [20, 80]=100 (removed first two item and it replace by 20 )


    */

    }

    }
```

---

Note:
No need to make any method for total i have already created one so use this to  double total(ArrayList list) call total in recursion function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask page**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: So firstly you need a method which will take the sum of a `List<Number>`.

Comment: your question is unclear. what do you mean by [ 40, 30 , 80] - > [ 20 ,80]

Comment: which part is unclear, Rajith Pemabandu

Comment: @samangamin: The functionality of the recursive part, and what you've done to attempt that part of the problem.

Comment: No need a method ,that is what i have mentioned in NOTE; you just have to call using total(list); @ Rogue

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what you're actually asking, and also `40+30+80` is `150`, not `170`, and it's not clear how the `30` becomes `20`

Comment: @Prune that is how the question has being asked  .evem i am frustrated with that .it needs to fix the array which give you a total number of 100 .

Comment: @samangamin: we have no idea of the process used to "fix" the array.  If you have no better description, then this is a question for the source of the problem.

Comment: Perhaps chop off elements until the sum is less than 100, and then pre-pend 100 minus the remaining sum ???  In any case, if *you* understand the process, you should make an attempt to code it and bring any problems back to us; if you don't understand, then it's a question for the source.

Comment: yeh but i don't actually know how to use recursive function in an array list.need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, something like this should satisfy it, but please note that recursion is not really the best way to achieve what you're apparently trying to do:

```
public static void count(ArrayList<Double> list) {
  if (list.empty()) {    
     return; // or consider using if/else
  }

  double total = total(list);

  if (total>100) {
    list.remove(0);
    count(list); // recursive call
  } else if (total<100) {
    list.add(0, 100-total);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly , i made it for my requirement using exactly yours .thank you soooooooo much @ Cupawn Tae